# Populating a listbox according to user selection

Tags: c#, xml

1. I am using C# to do this.
2. OK, so this is what my XML file looks like... only there are SO much more AUCCars nodes.

   ```
   <Recordset>
   <AUCCars>
       <Web_Series>5 Series</Web_Series>
           <Body_Desc>Sedan</Body_Desc>
           <Model_Type>550i (E60)</Model_Type>
           <Model_Year>2006</Model_Year>
           <Ext_Colour>Alpine White III - Non-Metallic</Ext_Colour>
           <Int_Colour>Leather Dakota Black - Dakota Leather</Int_Colour>
           <Price>R 579000</Price>
           <Search_Price>579000</Search_Price>
           <Province>Gauteng</Province>
           <AucID>106288</AucID>
           <DealerID>45</DealerID>
           <DealerCode>29968</DealerCode>
           <DealerName>Lyndhurst Auto</DealerName>
           <Transmission>Automatic</Transmission>
           <AirCon>n/a</AirCon>
           <Radio>Yes</Radio>
           <PSteering>Yes</PSteering>
           <ABS>Yes</ABS>
           <Airbag>Yes</Airbag>
           <Sunroof>Yes</Sunroof>
           <Km>11500</Km>
           <Motorplan>Yes</Motorplan>
           <Warranty>N</Warranty>
           <BodyNo>6CR76051</BodyNo>
           <ModelOEM>NB52</ModelOEM>
           <ColourOEM>300</ColourOEM>
           <TrimOEM>LCSW</TrimOEM>
           <WheelsOEM></WheelsOEM>
           <Sold>N</Sold>
           <Notes> </Notes>
           <Moreoptions>Automatic Transmission with Steptronic
                        Interior trim finishers, Fine-wood, Poplar Grain Brown, high-gloss
                        Park Distance Control (PDC),front and rear</Moreoptions>
           <Picture>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\frontview_big_P0300.jpg</Picture>
           <PictureRear>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\rearview_big_P0300.jpg</PictureRear>
           <Interior>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\Interior\big_Fo_LCSW.jpg</Interior>
   </AUCCars>
   <AUCCars>
           <Web_Series>5 Series</Web_Series>
           <Body_Desc>Sedan</Body_Desc>
           <Model_Type>550i (E60)</Model_Type>
           <Model_Year>2006</Model_Year>
           <Ext_Colour>Black Sapphire - Metallic</Ext_Colour>
           <Int_Colour>Amethyst Black Exclusive Leather - Exclusive Leather</Int_Colour>
           <Price>R 529990</Price>
           <Search_Price>529990</Search_Price>
           <Province>KwaZulu Natal</Province>
           <AucID>111922</AucID>
           <DealerID>17</DealerID>
           <DealerCode>2485</DealerCode>
           <DealerName>Supertech</DealerName>
           <Transmission>Automatic</Transmission>
           <AirCon> Yes</AirCon>
           <Radio>Yes</Radio>
           <PSteering>Yes</PSteering>
           <ABS>Yes</ABS>
           <Airbag>Yes</Airbag>
           <Sunroof>n/a</Sunroof>
           <Km>7000</Km>
           <Motorplan>n/a</Motorplan>
           <Warranty>N</Warranty>
           <BodyNo>6CR75567</BodyNo>
           <ModelOEM>NB52</ModelOEM>
           <ColourOEM>475</ColourOEM>
           <TrimOEM>LDRH</TrimOEM>
           <WheelsOEM></WheelsOEM>
           <Sold>N</Sold>
           <Notes> </Notes>
           <Moreoptions>Automatic Transmission with Steptronic
                        Electric Rear Screen Roller Sun Blind with manual Side Blinds
                        Interior trim finishers, Fine-wood, Poplar Grain Brown, high-gloss
                        High Beam Assist
                        Head-up display (not with SA354)</Moreoptions>
           <Picture>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\frontview_big_P0475.jpg</Picture>
           <PictureRear>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\rearview_big_P0475.jpg</PictureRear>
           <Interior>\Vehicle_Pictures\E60\LI\Interior\big_Fo_LDRH.jpg</Interior>  
   </AUCCars>
   <Recordset>
   ```
3. I need to fill combo boxes for Series, Model, and Year.
4. This i got right. When I compile the program, it loads all the series into the series
5. combo box.
6. When I selected a series, it automatically loads all the models into the models combo
7. box. When I selected a model, it automatically loads the years accordingly.
8. Now I need to display data according to selection.
9. eg. I selected "5 Series" for the series combo box, "550i (E60)" for the model combo 11. box, and "2006" for the year combo box.
10. How do I display all the data in that specific  node according to my selection 13. in a list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I hope I did get you right...* I created a *small sample form*. On **SelectedIndexChanged** of a **comboBox** I will **show** the **filtered aucCars**. ComboBoxes gets their *data from xml file* according to given details in question `(Web_Series, Model_Type, Model_Year - distinct)`

```
// get data from file
XElement aucCars = XElement.Load("data.xml");
private void cmbSeries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbSeries.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string currentSeries = cmbSeries.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var models = (from a in aucCars.Elements()
                        where a.Element("Web_Series").Value == currentSeries
                        select a.Element("Model_Type").Value).Distinct().ToList();
        cmbModel.DataSource = models;
    }
    showAucCars();
}
private void cmbModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbModel.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string currentSeries = cmbSeries.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string currentModel = cmbModel.SelectedItem.ToString();

        var years = (from a in aucCars.Elements()
                        where a.Element("Web_Series").Value == currentSeries &&
                        a.Element("Model_Type").Value == currentModel
                        select a.Element("Model_Year").Value).Distinct().ToList();
        cmbYear.DataSource = years;
    }
    showAucCars();
}
private void cmbYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showAucCars();
}
private void frmXmlLoad_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var series = (from a in aucCars.Elements()
                select a.Element("Web_Series").Value).Distinct().ToList();
    cmbSeries.DataSource = series;
}
private void showAucCars()
{
    var filterCars = aucCars.Elements();
    if (cmbSeries.SelectedItem!=null)
    {
        string currentSeries = cmbSeries.SelectedItem.ToString();
        filterCars = from a in filterCars
                        where a.Element("Web_Series").Value == currentSeries
                        select a;
    }
    if (cmbSeries.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string currentModel = cmbModel.SelectedItem.ToString();
        filterCars = from a in filterCars
                        where a.Element("Model_Type").Value == currentModel
                        select a;
    }
    if (cmbSeries.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string currentYear = cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
        filterCars = from a in filterCars
                        where a.Element("Model_Year").Value == currentYear
                        select a;
    }
    // will show all the element data 
    // add a new linq stmt to select specific elements
    listBox1.DataSource = filterCars.ToList();            
}
```

Within `showAucCars()` I **filter according to selection in comboBoxes** and show result in listBox. In case you want to *display a specific element* in listbox, add a **new linq stmt and select the according element(s)**.

Comment: Glad I could help - _in return you may consider **voting my answer up** and/or **marking** my response as best answer / solution_!